# Flink Streaming Kafka Source to Kafka Sink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am to trying write a Flink streaming code in Scala to read from Kafka topic and after doing some operation on message write the data back to Kafka Topic. I am using Flink Table API.

The code is running without any exception but did not see any message in Sink Topic.

Similar code is working fine when using MySQL as sink.

Not able to get what is the issue, the code is pretty straightforward as per Flink 1.9 documentation.

Please help me to get some clue to debug this issue.

Please find details:

**Flink Version** - 1.9

**Dependency** - SBT

**Kafka Version** - 2.1

**Kafka connector** - flink-connector-kafka-0.10 % 1.9.1

**Code**:

```java
    package com.flink

    // Import Packages
    import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
    import org.apache.flink.table.api._
    import org.apache.flink.types.Row
    import org.apache.flink.table.api.java._
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    import org.apache.flink.table.descriptors.Json
    import org.apache.flink.table.descriptors.Kafka
    import org.apache.flink.table.sinks.CsvTableSink
    import org.apache.flink.table.descriptors.Schema
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.Types
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka._
    import org.apache.flink.table.api.{Table, TableEnvironment}
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCAppendTableSink
    import org.apache.flink.table.api.java.StreamTableEnvironment
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment

    object kafkaToKafka2 {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        // Setting Streaming Environment
        val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
        env.enableCheckpointing(5000)

        // Define Table environment
        val tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)

        val schema = new Schema()
          .field("userId",Types.STRING)
          .field("jobTitleName", Types.STRING)
          .field("firstName", Types.STRING)
          .field("lastName", Types.STRING)

        val sinkSchema = new Schema()
          .field("user_id",Types.STRING)
          .field("job_name", Types.STRING)
          .field("name", Types.STRING)

        // Reading from Kafka
        tableEnv.connect(
          new Kafka()
            .version("0.10")
            .topic("sourceTopic")
            .property("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") // local
            .property("group.id", "poc1234")
            .startFromEarliest()
          //.startFromLatest()
        )
          .withFormat(
            new Json()
              .failOnMissingField(true)
              .deriveSchema()
          )
          .withSchema(schema)
          .inAppendMode()
          .registerTableSource("json_tab")

        // Writing to Kafka
        tableEnv.connect(
          new Kafka()
            .version("0.10")
            .topic("myTopic2")
            .property("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")   // local
            .property("group.id", "poc")
            .sinkPartitionerRoundRobin()

        )
          .withFormat(
            new Json()
              .failOnMissingField(false)
              .deriveSchema()
          )
          .withSchema(sinkSchema)
          .inAppendMode()
          .registerTableSink("json_sink_tab")

            // SQL query where we can do transformation using ANSI SQL
            val sql = "SELECT userId as user_id, jobTitleName as job_name, CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) as name " +
              "FROM json_tab " +
              "WHERE userId <> '' ";

            // Executing SQL query
            val result:Table = tableEnv.sqlQuery(sql)

        result.insertInto("json_sink_tab");

        // Printing Schema for checking purpose
        result.printSchema()
        System.out.println("======================= " + result.toString)

        env.execute("kafkaJsonJob")
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason, why you are using the old connector with a recent Kafka version? Could you please retry with `flink-connector-kafka`?

Comment: 2.11 sounds like a scala version number. There is no Kafka 2.11 (so far); the latest version is Kafka 2.4. What version of Kafka are you actually using?

Comment: Kafka Version - 2.1

Comment: As @ArvidHeise said, you need to update the connector. flink-connector-kafka-0.10 is for use with Kafka 0.10. Hopefully that will fix the problem.

Comment: Since you registered the operator chain on `tableEnv`, you should probably run the `execute()` on that, instead of `env`. Also, why exactly are you using the Table API for that?

Comment: FWIW, Kafka Streams or KSQL could be used to do this same task in less code

Comment: As per advice I have added "flink-connector-kafka" dependency and  also added jar in class path : 

flink-table-api-scala-bridge_2.12-1.9.1.jar,
flink-table-api-java-bridge_2.11-1.9.1.jar,
flink-table-planner_2.12-1.9.1.jar,
flink-table-api-scala_2.12-1.9.1.jar,
flink-table-common-1.9.1.jar

-- Still getting elow error:
"Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.NoMatchingTableFactoryException: Could not find a suitable table factory for 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableSourceFactory' in
the class path."

Please advice am I miising any other dependency ?